# How can i use more than 5 different icons in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table to which an icon must be applied according to the value of each cell, I have found a tool called "Formatting Rules" but it only allows me up to 5 different icons and I need 8 icons. These are the different conditions:

- icon1 when: `10 > val > 0`
- icon2 when: `25 > val > 10`
- icon3 when: `37 > val > 25`
- icon4 when: `50 > val > 37`
- icon5 when: `val = 71`
- icon6 when: `val = 72`
- icon7 when: `val = 73`
- icon8 when: `val = 74`

I have tried creating shapes using VBA code, but I prefer to use the icons that Excel brings by default.

Anyone know how I can solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: use more than one Conditional Formatting

Comment: Yes i tried that but the second conditional remove the icons applied by the first...

Comment: What formula did you use? How did you apply it? It may just need a (albeit a little deep) `IF()` with `AND()` and maybe `OR()`.

Comment: Im not using formula, Im using tool called "Formatting Rules" with the option "Format all cells based on their values", It is the only option that allows me to set an icon

Comment: @Joseph Posted a late response to your 2017-question, might be worth to have a look on :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late, but you can using IFS formula with circle symbols from https://www.i2symbol.com/symbols/circle

They have 9 different circle color. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea, you might try the following

- as Worksheet event code and
- profiting from Excel's `UniChar()` function:

```
Option Explicit                            ' code module head in a Sheet(!) module

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        Target.NumberFormat = getFormat(Target.value)
    End If
End Sub

Function getFormat(ByVal value, Optional ByVal pattern As String = " 0;-#0;") As String
'a) define (11) start values to be compared
    Dim vals: vals = Array(-100000, 1, 11, 26, 38, 50, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75)
'b) define (11) decimal icon numbers to be translated into unicharacters later (note: 32=blank)
    Dim nums: nums = Array(32, 128467, 128468, 127381, 128470, 32, 128466, 127383, 9786, 9785, 32)
'c) loop through start vals in reverse order
    Dim i As Long
    For i = UBound(vals) To 0 Step -1
        If value >= vals(i) Then Exit For   ' check conditions
    Next
'd) return icons1-8
    getFormat = Chr(34) & Application.WorksheetFunction.Unichar(nums(i)) & Chr(34) & pattern

End Function
```

**Note**

Change the unicode numbers in (b) to any decimal or hexadecimal values as needed, the above values only demonstrate the principle.

You'll find enough unicode lists in the web coming close to your needed icons used in the mentioned program.